# return blank array in php function

Tags: php, mysql, function

my code is below for fetching records according to count value

```
function getcatdatafromlocal($count)
        {        $obj= new LocaldbConnection;
                $obj->connecttolocaldb();
                $obj2=new wpdbConnection;
                $obj2->connecttowpdb();
                //global $count;
                echo $count;     //right now count value is 489
                 if($count==NULL)
                 {
                 $count=0;
                 }
            echo    $a="SELECT * FROM  m5201100380.voruflokkar where akv_nr >'".$count."' ORDER BY akv_nr ASC Limit 4";
            echo "<br/>";
                $sql_get_cat_local=mysql_query($a); //here non of record is found  because there is no record which has `akv_nr`>489.
                $cnt=0;
            //  $rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql_get_cat_local);
            //  print_r($rows);
                echo "<br/>";
                $id=array();
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql_get_cat_local))
                {       
                    $cnt++;


                        $id[]=$rows['akv_nr'];


                }

                echo "brfore cnt <br/>";
                if($cnt==0)
                {       echo "no record to found <br/>";
                        $count=0;
                        $this->getcatdatafromlocal($count);

                }
                /* $rdk=array();
                for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++)
                {
                    $rdk[$i]=$id[$i];
                } */

            //  print_r($id);
                echo "<br/>";
                 echo "<pre>";
                 echo "print var_dump <br/>";
                var_dump($id);
                echo "</pre>"; 
                return $id;

        }
```

And output of this function is here:

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/25749/20150312-tchj-94kb.jpg

The question is that `print var_dump` part is execute two time?

Answer (score 0):

$a="SELECT * FROM  m5201100380.voruflokkar where count(akv_nr) >'".$count."' ORDER BY akv_nr ASC Limit 4";

your r getting result twice beacuse, var_dump($id) providing result also you
returning $id again, so its showing result twice

Comment: i put return in comment,still there is no change